# checkbox total price update

Tags: javascript

I'm in pain already with this issue, I need the checkbox if clicked to increase the "total" price with the amount of items selected like so:
not checked: demo = selectedQty * price,
if checked: Total = demo + selectedQty * 1

```
<?php include include 'includes/head.php';
        $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest'));
        $time_s = $dt->format('Y/m/d, H:i:s');
        ?>
        <?php include 'includes/template_header.php';
        if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'your order has been placed';
            } else {
                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                    $place_order = array(
                    'time_s'       => $_POST['time_s'],
                    'user_id'      => $_POST['user_id'],
                    'img_no'       => $_POST['img_no'],
                    'ref_no'       => $_POST['ref_no'],
                    'sha_no'       => $_POST['sha_no'],
                    'lar_no'       => $_POST['lar_no'],
                    'first_name'   => $_POST['first_name'],
                    'last_name'    => $_POST['last_name'],
                    'email'     => $_POST['email'],
                    'phone'     => $_POST['phone'],
                    'website'      => $_POST['website'],
                    'company'      => $_POST['company'],
                    'message'      => $_POST['message']);
                    place_order($place_order); 
                    die("<script>location.href = 'preturi.php?success'</script>");
                    exit();
                } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
                    echo output_errors($errors);
            }?>
        <div id="calculator" style="margin:5%">
        <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" style="width:100%;" />
        <br />
        <input type="number" id="sliderval" /><br />
        <p id="total" style="display:inline-block">0</p></div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="addon" value="1" />
        <?php if (logged_in() === true){ ?>
        <div style="margin:5%">
        <form action="" method="post" name="comanda">
        <p>
        <input name="time_s" type="text" value="<?php echo $time_s;?>" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>
        <input name="user_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['user_id'];?>" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>
        <input name="last_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['last_name'];?>" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>
        <input name="first_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name'];?>" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['email'];?>" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>Telefon:<br />
        <input name="phone" type="text" /></p>
        <p>Website:<br />
        <input name="website" type="text" /></p>
        <p>Companie:<br />
        <input name="company" type="text" /></p>
        <p>
        <input name="img_no" type="number" id="sliderval1" style="display:none"/></p>
        <p>Mesaj:<br />
        <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Trimite" />
        <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        </form></div>
        <script>

        $('#sliderval').on('input', function() {
           var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();

            $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });
        $('#sliderval').on('input', function() {
           var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
            $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });
        $('#sliderval1').on('input', function() {
           var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
            $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });
        $('#sliderval1').on('input', function() {
           var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
            $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });
        $("#slider").on('change',function() {
            var selectedQty = $(this).val();
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });  
        $("#slider").on('change',function() {
            var selectedQty = $(this).val();
            $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
            $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
            calc(selectedQty);
        });  
        function calc(selectedQty) {
          var itemTotal = 0;
             switch (true) {
                case (selectedQty <= 2) :
                    itemTotal = 6.5 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 5) :
                    itemTotal = 5.9 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 15) :
                    itemTotal = 5.5 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 30) :
                    itemTotal = 5 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 60) :
                    itemTotal = 4.5 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 100) :
                    itemTotal = 4 * selectedQty;
                    break;
                case (selectedQty <= 200) :
                    itemTotal = 3.6 * selectedQty;
                    break;  
                case (selectedQty <= 500) :
                    itemTotal = 3.4 * selectedQty;
                    break;       
                default:
                    itemTotal = 3.2 * selectedQty;
                    break;
            }
            $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
        }

        <?  }else{ echo '<div style="margin:5%">Pentru a plasa comanda trebuie sa inregistrat si autentificat.</div>';}?>

          </script>
        <?php } include 'includes/template_footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code

Comment: @CiprianKis I updated the post for what you desired. Now when the slider is at a quantity of 1000, the price shows at 4200. If I have answered your question, can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:

```
<?  }else{ echo '<div style="margin:5%">Pentru a plasa comanda trebuie sa  inregistrat si autentificat.</div>';}?>

</script>
```

`echo` is not valid Javascript. It will not work. You need to get the echo out of the `</script>` closing tag.

Now for a response to the front end portion of your question.

Here you go. I added an id to the checkbox and then altered the elements required not only if it is checked while you move the checkbox, but also if you move the slider and then click the checkbox.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/semj4fk4/).

Note that it enters the total to `demo` when not checked and the total to `total` when checked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="calculator" style="margin:5%">
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" style="width:100%;" /> <!-- quantity -->
<input type="number" id="sliderval" /> <!-- quantity -->
<input id="checker" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="1" /> <!-- this one -->
<p id="total" style="display:inline-block">0</p> <!-- total -->
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
/***NEW CODE BELOW***/
$('#checker').click(function(){
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
  $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  var val = calc(selectedQty);
  if($('#checker').prop('checked')){ 
    val += Number(selectedQty);
    $('#total').text(val); 
    }
  else{          
      $('#demo').text(val);
  }  
 });
/***NEW CODE ABOVE***/

$('#sliderval').on('input', function () {
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
  $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval').on('input', function () {
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
  $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval1').on('input', function () {
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
  $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval1').on('input', function () {
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
  $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  calc(selectedQty);
});
$("#slider").on('change', function () {
  var selectedQty = $(this).val();
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
calc(selectedQty);
});
$("#slider").on('change', function () {
  var selectedQty = $(this).val();
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
calc(selectedQty);
});

function calc(selectedQty) {
var itemTotal = 0;
switch (true) {
    case (selectedQty <= 2):
        itemTotal = 6.5 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 5):
        itemTotal = 5.9 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 15):
        itemTotal = 5.5 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 30):
        itemTotal = 5 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 60):
        itemTotal = 4.5 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 100):
        itemTotal = 4 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 200):
        itemTotal = 3.6 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 500):
        itemTotal = 3.4 * selectedQty;
        break;
    default:
        itemTotal = 3.2 * selectedQty;
        break;
}

/***NEW CODE BELOW***/
  if($('#checker').prop('checked')){
      $('#total').text(itemTotal);
    }
  else{    
      $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
  }
/***NEW CODE ABOVE***/
return itemTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the desired behaviour you require has been achieved in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melbournedesign/rmf9vepw/). Please click the link and check.

The code below was added to your javascript file to achieve the behaviour.

```
$(".addon").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
   $('#total').text(itemTotal);  
    }
```

Comment: @Ciprian Kis I used the original code you posted in the question. Please let me know if my solution works for what you want.

Comment: I do believe you are closer to the result than I am, but still not there,.. as an example, if you push the slider to 1000, this is the quantity, the price total is 3200, but clicking the checkbox would add anothe 1 per unit, so without the checkbox at 1000 units the price should be 3200, with the checkbox 4200.. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @A.Sharma, his answer was 99.99% on the money but pointed out what i was missing. His answer + a small adjustment. I bet I didn't explain the thing to well, otherwise he would've nailed it in first try. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/semj4fk4/3/)

```
<div id="calculator" style="margin:5%">
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="1" style="width:100%;" /> <!-- quantity -->
    <input type="number" id="sliderval" /> <!-- quantity -->
    <input id="checker" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="1" /> <!-- this one -->
    <p id="demo" style="display:inline-block">0</p> <!-- total -->
</div>

<script>
$('#checker').click(function(){
  var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
  $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
  $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
  calc(selectedQty);

  if($('#checker').prop('checked')){ 
    $('#total').text(itemTotal); 
    }
  else{          
      $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
  }  
});

$('#sliderval').on('input', function() {
   var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();

    $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval').on('input', function() {
   var selectedQty = $('#sliderval').val();
    $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval1').on('input', function() {
   var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
    $('#slider').val(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});
$('#sliderval1').on('input', function() {
   var selectedQty = $('#sliderval1').val();
    $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});
$("#slider").on('change',function() {
    var selectedQty = $(this).val();
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderval').val(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});  
$("#slider").on('change',function() {
    var selectedQty = $(this).val();
    $('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);
    $('#sliderval1').val(selectedQty);
    calc(selectedQty);
});  
function calc(selectedQty) {
  var itemTotal = 0;
     switch (true) {
        case (selectedQty <= 2) :
            itemTotal = 6.5 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 5) :
            itemTotal = 5.9 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 15) :
            itemTotal = 5.5 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 30) :
            itemTotal = 5 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 60) :
            itemTotal = 4.5 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 100) :
            itemTotal = 4 * selectedQty;
            break;
        case (selectedQty <= 200) :
            itemTotal = 3.6 * selectedQty;
            break;  
        case (selectedQty <= 500) :
            itemTotal = 3.4 * selectedQty;
            break;       
        default:
            itemTotal = 3.2 * selectedQty;
            break;
    }
    if($('#checker').prop('checked')){
          $('#demo').text(itemTotal + selectedQty * 1);
        }
      else{    
          $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
      }
}
</script>
```